# OpenCV List available cameras Plugged in

Tags: macos, qt, opencv, window

i want use OpenCV for List Camera , i have source use COM MS but i want it run also on MACOS, can you help me

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the native `QTKit` framework on the Macintosh (not to be confused with [Nokia's QT cross platform application framework](http://qt.nokia.com/)), you can do [`[QTCaptureDevice inputDevicesWithMediaType: QTMediaTypeVideo];`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/QTCaptureDevice/inputDevicesWithMediaType%3a) (documentation is linked for you).

Comment: hi, can QTCaptureDevice run on Windows & macos ???

Answer (score 0):

I would use QMediaTypeVideo because I think it is a better choise for me but that is a 
oppenion so you all don't hafe to agry with me.Well that is my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[cvCaptureFromCAM()](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#capturefromcam) uses [VFW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757708%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as a backend on Windows, [V4L](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video4Linux) as a backend on Linux and now uses QuickTime as a backend on OS X.

However there is no function in the HighGUI that lists connected cameras. As far as I can tell they just expect you to call cvCaptureFromCAM(i) with i=0 and increasing and check if the result is NULL.

Just keep in mind that cvCaptureFromCAM is part of HighGUI not OpenCV core and so is expected to be used mainly for prototyping.

Comment: i cant download libwebcam, can you share link download it ???